# Loop through an array to create routes in react router

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

I want to hit an API which returns me all the routes of the website that I will need for the react website.

I'm not entirely sure on how to do it or even google an example.

My code looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute pageId={5} background="" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/your-journey" background="" pageId={7} component={YourJourney}/>
      <Route path="/designed-for-you" background="" pageId={6} component={DesignedForYou}/>
      <Route path="/join-us" background="" pageId={1} component={JoinUs}/>
      <Route path="/get-in-touch" background="no-hero-image" pageId={4} component={GetInTouch}/>
      <Route path="/legal-and-compliance" background="no-hero-image" pageId={8} component={Legal}/>
      <Route path="/privacy" background="no-hero-image" pageId={9} component={Privacy}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Where everything under the Route path="/" needs to come from the API.

Comment: You can to make the get request prior to rendering router. and use the response to generate route component.

Comment: Do you have any links to docs for that?

Comment: What have you already tried? Also please note that JSX is just syntactic sugar for React.createElement(...) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, just load the data in some action that loads your routes and map over the result in your `ReactDOM.render` function. It'll look something like this:

```
// This just maps the component string names (keys) to actual react components (values)
const COMPONENT_MAP = {
  'Privacy': Privacy, // quotes are not necessary, just illustrating the difference a bit more
  // ... other mappings
}

// Some asynch action that loads the routes from your API
getRoutes().then((routes) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute pageId={5} background="" component={Home}/>
          {routes.map((r) => {
             return <Route path={r.path} background={r.bg} pageId={r.pageId} component={COMPONENT_MAP[r.component]}/>
           }}
        </Route>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try now

Comment: how to do looping more than one level hierarchy? for ex:

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute pageId={5} background="" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/your-journey" background="" pageId={7} component={YourJourney}>
         <IndexRoute pageId={9} background="" component={XYZ}/>
         <Route path="/xyz" component={XYZ}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
    </Route>
  </Router>