# React js - Loop obj route path to create react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return my routes from an object using loop. I'm following the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807322/loop-through-an-array-to-create-routes-in-react-router) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564989/loop-through-an-array-to-create-routes) . It's working well, but when i have another single route it won't showing the page on browser, and there's no error. Those anyone helping me to fix my code ?
Here is my code:

```
export function RouteStudent(props) {
    const routeList = [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "Profile",
        "Description": "",
        "PathURI": "/profile",
        "Slug": "Profile",
        "URI": "/",        
        "Child": []
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "Product",
        "Description": "",
        "PathURI": "/product",
        "Slug": "Product",
        "URI": "/",
        "Child": [
            {
                "ID": "3",
                "Name": "Item A",
                "Description": "",
                "PathURI": "/product/item-a",
                "Slug": "ItemA",
                "URI": "/item-a"
            },
            {
                "ID": "4",
                "Name": "Item B",
                "Description": "",
                "PathURI": "/product/item-b",
                "Slug": "ItemB",
                "URI": "/item-b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "5",
        "Name": "Sales",
        "Description": "",
        "PathURI": "/sales",
        "Slug": "Sales",
        "URI": "/",
        "Child": [
            {
                "ID": "6",
                "Name": "Sale A",
                "Description": "",
                "PathURI": "/sales/sale-a",
                "Slug": "SaleA",
                "URI": "/saleA"
            },
            {
                "ID": "7",
                "Name": "Sale B",
                "Description": "",
                "PathURI": "/sales/sale-b",
                "Slug": "SaleB",
                "URI": "/sale-b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "Name": "Billing",
        "Description": "",
        "PathURI": "/billing",
        "Slug": "Billing",
        "URI": "/",        
        "Child": []
    },,
    {
        "ID": "9",
        "Name": "Regulation",
        "Description": "",
        "PathURI": "/regulation",
        "Slug": "Regulation",
        "URI": "/",        
        "Child": []
    },
    
];
    const COMPONENT_MAP = {
        'Dashboard': Dashboard,
        'Profile':Profile,
        'Product':Product,
        'ItemA':ItemA,
        'ItemB':ItemB,
        'Sales':Sales,
        'SaleA':SaleA,
        'SaleB':SaleB,
        'Billing':Billing,
        'Regulation':Regulation,
    }
    console.log(routeList);
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<h3>Loading..</h3>}>
            <Switch>
                { <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard"/> }                
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact/>
                <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                
                {(Object.keys(routeList).length > 0) ?(
                    routeList.map((v)=>
                    (( Object.keys(v.Child).length > 0) ? (                        
                        <Route
                            path={v.PathURI}
                            render={({ match: { url } }) => (
                            <>
                                <Route path={`${url}/`} component={COMPONENT_MAP[v.Slug]} exact />
                                {v.Child.map((k)=>
                                    <Route path={`${url+k.URI}`} component={COMPONENT_MAP[k.Slug]} />
                                )}
                            </>
                            )}
                        />  
                    ) : (
                        <Route path={v.PathURI} component={COMPONENT_MAP[v.Slug]} />
                    ) )
                )  
                ) : '' }              
                

                <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
                

            </Switch>            
        </Suspense>
    )
}

export default RouteStudent;
```

When i typing the path uri on browser, route **Dashboard, Profile, Product (and the child), Sales(and the child)** it works well, i mean showing the page. **But when accessing route Billing and Regulation it's not working**, show the blank (suck as doesn't have page). But when i write like this:

```
<Route path="/billing" component={Billing} />
```

it show the page.

Can anyone help what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-loop-obj-route-path-to-create-react-routes-ufr55) and it seems all your routes are accessible.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, example also works for me.

Comment: You did have an extraneous comma in the middle of your `routeList` array, but I assume that was a typo in your question.